# Updating google consents on React Native Application

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-analytics, react-native-firebase

I recently received an email from google asking to modify some params related to analytics. I am having issues trying to update the value of ad_storage.

When i read the documentation, i can not find how to do it in react native. I see this for swift

```
Analytics.setConsent([
  .analyticsStorage: .granted,
  .adStorage: .granted,
  .adUserData: .granted,
  .adPersonalization: .granted,
])
```

However, i am using @react-native-firebase/analytics and i can not see the `setContent` function, can anyone help me with this issue? I need to ask the user and update those values.

Comment: From [issue #6636](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/discussions/6636) on the repo, it seems like consent tracking has not been implemented in React Native Firebase.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!  I have no idea about how to fix this before march (Google's deadline for updating consents).

Answer (score 0):

The `setContent` function it's been merged with this PR https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/pull/7629.